# Moving window RMQ performance improvement

Tags: c++, algorithm, rmq

Say I have an array of integers `A` of length `N`, also I have an integer `L` <= `N`.

What I am trying to find is the minimum of the range [0, L-1],  [1,L], [2,L+1]....[N-L,N-1]

*(like a moving window of length `L` from left to right)*

---

My algorithm now is O(N lg N) with O(N lg N) preprocess:

1. Save all numbers `A[0...L-1]` in a multi-set `S`, also store the number in a queue `Q` in order. The minimum of [0, L-1] is simply the first element of `S`. O(N lg N)
2. Pop out the first element of `Q`, find this element in `S` and delete it. Then push `A[L]` in `S`. The minimum of [1, L] is simply the  first element of `S`. O(lg N)
3. Repeat step 2 for all possible range, move to next element each iteration. O(N)

Total is O(N lg N).

---

I wonder if there is any algorithm which can achieve better than this with following requirements:

1. Preprocess time (If needed) is O(N)
2. Query time if O(1)

I have done some research on RMQ, the nearest method I found is using sparse table which achieve O(1) query time but O(N lg N) preprocess time.  Another method which [reduce RMQ to LCA](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/#A%20O(N),%20O(1)%20algorithm%20for%20the%20restricted%20RMQ) problem can meet the requirements but it needs some restriction on the array `A`.

So is it possible that, with no restriction on `A`, the requirements can be fulfilled when solving my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a [deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/). We will keep the elements sorted ascendingly, so the first element is always the minimum in `[i - L + 1, i]`, for the current position `i`. We won't keep actual elements, but their positions.

```
d = empty deque
for i = 0 to n-1:

    // get rid of too old elements
    while !d.empty && i - d.front + 1 > L:
        d.pop_front()

    // keep the deque sorted
    while !d.empty && A[d.back] > A[i]        
        d.pop_back()

    d.push_back(i)
    // A[d.front] is the minimum in `[i - L + 1, i]
```

Since every element enters and leaves the deque at most once, this is `O(n)`.

Comment: This is so brilliant, never thought of this...thanks!!